# How to send message using LinPhone SDK?

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk, voip-android

I am building an android application where I am using [LinPhone SDK](http://www.linphone.org/products) for audio/ video and sending message using VoIP.

I read a lot of blog and finally I got a [EasyLinphone](https://github.com/forever4313/EasyLinphone) GitHub Code using LinPhone SDK for audio/ Video calling. I read this code as I am yet doing RND on it.

Finally I am able to do audio and video call but there is no option of sending instance message.

If someone have use LinPhone SDK and know what to do for sending message please let me know.

As LinPhone SDK documentation are to out-date.

Comment: I don't understand the term "instance message" - do you mean an "Instant"/chat message, a SIP Info message...?

Comment: chat message using LinPhone SDK

Comment: @PPartisan do you have any solution how to work for message chat using linPhone libry

Comment: I haven't used the messaging feature in Linphone before, sorry, I only have some experience with making calls

Comment: @PPartisan Do you have experience in making call with linphone libr ?

Comment: @PPartisan if you have download code from https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android official gitHub code might be you have phase issue path is empty. Do you have any idea how to fix it